# Visual Basic 2015 project for VB.NET to work in XP

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, windows-xp

Apologies for my lack of knowledge as I do not have much experience.

I have created a VB.NET application using visual basic 2015 however, when I tried to run the application on XP Professional Version 2002 SP3 I get the follow error message.

I have for the life of me do not know how to fix this. The .net framework which the application was created in was 4.5.2.

The application works perfectly on Windows 7 and Windows 10.

However, issues are only on XP

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 5.1.2600.196608 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.269
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.269 (RTMGDR.030319-2600)
dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)
```

```
SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/rwuser/Desktop/Disk%20Cleanup%20Toolkit/drive_cleanup.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Documents and Settings\rwuser\Desktop\Disk Cleanup Toolkit\drive_cleanup.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception reading manifest from file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/rwuser/Desktop/Disk%20Cleanup%20Toolkit/drive_cleanup.application: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Manifest XML signature is not valid.
        + SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [28/07/2016 09:56:20] : Activation of C:\Documents and Settings\rwuser\Desktop\Disk Cleanup Toolkit\drive_cleanup.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [28/07/2016 09:56:21] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
        - Exception reading manifest from file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/rwuser/Desktop/Disk%20Cleanup%20Toolkit/drive_cleanup.application: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (SignatureValidation)
        - Manifest XML signature is not valid.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSignature(Stream s)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
        - SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied.
        - Source: System.Security
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignedInfo(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
            at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignature(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
            at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignatureReturningKey(AsymmetricAlgorithm& signingKey)
            at System.Deployment.Internal.CodeSigning.SignedCmiManifest.Verify(CmiManifestVerifyFlags verifyFlags)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSignature(Stream s)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: Windows XP is now obsolete. Better to do not think about it.

Comment: I know but the company I work for still uses XP!! lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XP only supports the .NET Framework up to version 4.0. If you want to run it on XP you'll need to change the target framework to 4 and re-compile the project.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/p/dotnet45xp/

Comment: I did that but after much toying around it did not solve the issue. Instead on my script i was using WMI query which in effect did not work great with XP.. so changed WIM to system managementSearch and that got it working.